# Error installig pycairo on Linux: missing cairo.h

Tags: pycairo

Trying to install pycairo I get a missing C lib `cairo.h`. I already have installed `libcairo2-dev` and updated `pip3`. Any ideas on how to fix?

```
pip install pycairo
Collecting pycairo
  Using cached pycairo-1.21.0.tar.gz (340 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycairo
  Building wheel for pycairo (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/dbarcene/anaconda3/bin/python /home/dbarcene/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp_4nbw_f7
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-3i43xt78/pycairo_0149ed3d8f314887ad96f80dbc14140d
  Complete output (21 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/cairo
  copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/cairo
  copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/cairo
  copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/cairo
  running build_ext
  building 'cairo._cairo' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/cairo
  /home/dbarcene/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dbarcene/anaconda3/include -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/dbarcene/anaconda3/include -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=21 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=0 -I/usr/lib/include/cairo -I/usr/lib/include -I/usr/lib/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/include -I/usr/lib/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/lib/include -I/usr/lib/include/uuid -I/usr/lib/include -I/usr/lib/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib/include/libpng16 -I/usr/lib/include -I/home/dbarcene/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c cairo/bufferproxy.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/cairo/bufferproxy.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
  In file included from cairo/private.h:42:0,
                   from cairo/bufferproxy.c:34:
  cairo/pycairo.h:37:10: fatal error: cairo.h: No such file or directory
   #include <cairo.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command '/home/dbarcene/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo
```

Comment: What linux distro are you using?  And what version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am using anaconda I tried installing through conda with the command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 pycairo
```

It checked for several inconsistencies in my base env, but at the end it installed using a "Package Plan" with this contents:

```
## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/dbarcene/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - pycairo


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    ca-certificates-2018.10.15 |       ha4d7672_0         135 KB  conda-forge/label/gcc7
    pybind11-2.4.3             |   py38hfd86e86_0         134 KB
    pycairo-1.21.0             |   py38h287db57_0         120 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         389 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  jinja2             pkgs/main/noarch::jinja2-2.11.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pybind11           pkgs/main/linux-64::pybind11-2.4.3-py38hfd86e86_0
  pycairo            pkgs/main/linux-64::pycairo-1.21.0-py38h287db57_0
  pycodestyle        pkgs/main/noarch::pycodestyle-2.6.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyflakes           pkgs/main/noarch::pyflakes-2.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2022.4.26-~ --> conda-forge/label/gcc7::ca-certificates-2018.10.15-ha4d7672_0
```

I also checked in a console `import cairo` and it seems to work. There are certainly some dependencies broken that I haven't figured out yet, but this might serve as a workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [pipy page for pycairo](https://pypi.org/project/pycairo/):

> Installing Pycairo requires cairo including its headers. For more info see “Getting Started”.

The [linked page](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) gives the following instructions:

> Installing Pycairo requires pkg-config and cairo including its
> headers. Here are some examples on how to install those for some
> platforms:
>
> - Ubuntu/Debian: `sudo apt install libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev`
> - macOS/Homebrew: `brew install cairo pkg-config`
> - Arch Linux: `sudo pacman -S cairo pkgconf`
> - Fedora: `sudo dnf install cairo-devel pkg-config python3-devel`
> - openSUSE: `sudo zypper install cairo-devel pkg-config python3-devel`

And I guess that the Fedora instructions will work for RHEL / CentOS too, modulo possibly using `yum` rather than `dnf`.

Comment: I already have those packages installed.

Comment: Well I think you must be missing a "dev" or "devel" package for Cairo.  That is where the missing "cairo.h" header file should come from.